# Clarification on variable importance (i.e., impurity mode) for Ranger random forest regression model

Tags: r, random-forest, importance

[Ranger documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/ranger.pdf) states that if the importance mode is set to 'Impurity', then the estimated measure is '...the variance of the responses for regression..." Could someone expand on this or provide a relevant publication? As a starting point for an answer, I'm assuming it is something like the the sum of all the differences in response variance between nodes pre/post split where the feature of interest is used...maybe normalized by the number of trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the weighted variance of the response in the two child nodes. We don't need the pre-split variance for optimization because that won't change with potential split points.

With notation of [Ishwaran 2015](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10994-014-5451-2) Eq. (2):

$$\hat{D}(s,t) = \hat{p}(t_L) \hat{\Delta}(t_L) + \hat{p}(t_R) \hat{\Delta}(t_R)$$,

where $t$ is the current node, $s$ is the split point, $\hat{p}(t_L)$, $\hat{p}(t_R)$ are the proportion of data in the left/right child node and $\hat{\Delta}(t_L)$,$\hat{\Delta}(t_R)$ are the response variances in the child nodes.

You can also call it sum of squares splitting, since the denominator cancels out if you include the current node variance.